# Программа не находит MSVCR100D.dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Была написана программа с использованием библиотеки windows.h.
При переносе на другой компьютер выдает такую ошибку:

> [image: Запуск программы невозможен, отсутствие MSVCR100D.dll]

Можно ли как-нибудь переносить вместе с программой необходимую библиотеку, чтобы не устанавливать дополнительное ПО на другие компьютеры? Если да, то как это реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разумеется, можно! Просто положите нужную dll в каталог, откуда стартует программа.

Кроме того, MSVCR*.dll — это не библиотека с WinAPI, это рантайм-библиотека C++. Её вам придётся таскать с собой практически всегда.

Кстати, вы компилируете debug-версию (поэтому используется MSVCR100**D**.dll), а для инсталляции вам понадобится скорее всего release.

Comment: Стоить заметить еще что линковать рантайм библиотеки С++ можно и статически, тогда ничего ложить никуда не нужно.

Comment: Кстати, да, хорошая опция. Но возможна ли статическая линковка с C++/CLI (WinForms говорит о том, что это не чистый C++)?

Comment: а как выглядит такая линковка? что изменяется в настройках проекта?

Comment: Ключи /MT(Release) и /MTd (Debug) если не ошибаюсь.

Comment: @cpp_user: Попробовал, получил `1>cl : Command line error D8016: '/clr' and '/MTd' command-line options are incompatible`.

Comment: А вообще, есть ли смысл тащить за собой эту библиотеку? или проще каждый раз пользоваться из состава ОС?

Comment: И вот документация: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ffkc918h.aspx. К сожалению, слинковать вместе не выйдет.

Comment: @Corvin: имеет, в ОС её нету.

Comment: @Corvin: Но даже если бы и была, вы хотите DLL Hell? Представьте себе, что кто-то заменит её на немного другую версию. Лучше всё таскать с собой, винты уже давно дешёвые.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Разобрался. Все работает.

Comment: Статически с /clr это наверное фантастика была бы. ;-)

Comment: @VladD, какая "немного другая версия" может быть у рантайма С++? Ну да, у 8го рантайма была проблема с установкой. Но у 10го ее давно исправили...

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Сошлюсь на [статью Реймонда](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/04/11/10516280.aspx). И да, у MSVCR*.dll есть разные версии, приходящие с разными сервис-паками Visual Studio.

Comment: В той статье писали про другую библиотеку. Что же до сервис-паков - они же совместимы.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Совместимы при перекомпиляции — скорее всего, да (если другого не написано в release notes). А вот в бинарной совместимости я бы не был так уверен.

Comment: @VladD, им не стали бы давать одинаковые имена, если бы в Microsoft не были уверены в совместимости. Напомню, что установка redistributable package в систему - это вообще-то штатный способ установки, который придумали сами разработчики рантайма.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Одинаково называть приходится, иначе нет смысла. В любом случае, _зачем-то_ в манифесте вы можете указать, какая конкретно версия рантайма вам подходит, а какая лучше пожалуйста не надо.

Comment: Да, точно, про манифест я совсем забыл, хотя 5 лет назад очень долго с этими манифестами разбирался :) Так ведь это и решает проблему: будет загружен нужный рантайм, независимо от того, сколько сервис-паков поверх поставил пользователь. И в SxS никто этот рантайм не заменит ничем другим.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Кстати, да. Об этом всё время забывают почему-то, а техника мощная.

Answer (score 3):

Библиотека, положенная в папку с программой - это, конечно же, рабочий вариант (если не забыть про манифест к ней). Но если не упомянуть о другом способе, ответ будет неполным.

Можно скачать с сайта майкрософта и установить Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package ([x86](http://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/download/details.aspx?id=5555), [x64](http://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/download/details.aspx?id=14632)). Также эти установочники допускается распространять вместе с вашей программой, если нет желания заставлять пользователей скачивать их самостоятельно.

Comment: Этот вариант является наиболее верным, т.к. не засоряет систему тоннами одинаковых библиотек. Кроме того, позволяет подменять оные на самые последние, исправленные версии.

Comment: Зачем манифест?

Comment: Некоторые версии рантайма (8й точно, про другие не знаю) не могут быть найдены системным загрузчиком без манифеста, даже если будут 10 раз лежать в той же папке.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Ыыы? Можете подкинуть ссылку? Интересно, как такое смогло произойти.

Comment: Ссылку не подкину, а как такое могло произойти - поясню. В исполнимый файл студией внедряется манифест, в котором прописано, какая версия рантайма нужна. При наличии такой записи в манифесте загрузчик будет загружать библиотеку только в том случае, если у нее тоже есть манифест, и в нем прописана нужная версия. Произойти такое смогло, собственно, после введения манифестов и механизма SxS.